# Passing Domain Name as Parameter With ASP.Net MVC Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

In one of our web application, i need to send domain name (ex: domainname.com) as parameter with asp.net mvc routing. So i created a route definition like below:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AccountDetail",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{htip}/{dname}",
        defaults: new {
            controller = "Account",
            action = "Index"
        },           
    );
```

Also i have a method defined in AccountController like below:

```
public ActionResult Details(string htip, string dname) { }
```

According to the this route config and method declared in controller, MVC generates urls like `http://localhost:63740/Account/Details/N/domainname.com` and this is what i expect.
But if i follow this url, IIS's 404 error page welcomes me instead of any MVC related page. Because MVC doesn't handle the url, because of TLD at the end (.com).

How can i achieve to make MVC handle these urls?

Comment: did you try someting like {dname}.{ext}. So you will have two parameters instead of one

Comment: i hadn't tried that way but just tried after your message. and the result is same as i expected. If IIS detects .{ext} at the enf of URL, handle itself.

Comment: @LostInComputer yes, you are right. i found my answer at that questions. before asking question, i searched a lot but couldn't find it. thanks.